# how to stop html encoding from replacing double spaces with single spaces in swift 4

Tags: html, swift, character-encoding, whitespace

I've got the following string:

```
tweetContent = "Hello  World!"
```

As you can see, it's got two spaces. Which is what I want.

Now I need to encode that string to check for HTML character such as `&amp;`. I do that with the following line of code:

```
let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
                data: tweetContent.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                documentAttributes: nil)
```

The problem with that is, it replaces the double space in my string to a single space. Which is not what I want. How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Double spaces will display as a single space in HTML anyway.

Comment: The problem is, that I use the character count for coloring the text with NSAttributedText.